# Calling a stored procedure stored in Snowflake from Script Activity in ADF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

When I try to execute a stored procedure in Snowflake from a Script Activity in Azure Data Factory, I got this error:

> ERROR [42000] SQL compilation error:
> Syntax error line 1 at position 15 unexpected 'DCA_TEST1_DB'.

I have successfully configured a Snowflake linked services.

I put this code in the script:

```
@concat('CALL PROCEDURE DCA_TEST1_DB.DB_TEST1.UpdateSalesforceAccount();')
```

I have tested the procedure is running OK.

I'm not sure if I can use a script activity for this.

Comment: just simply you can use ` CALL Databsename.schemaname.Procedutrname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution!

1- In Store procedure on Snowflake write the objects whit double quote, like this:

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DCA_TEST1_DB.DB_TEST1.UPDATESALESFORCEACCOUNT()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE SQL
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
BEGIN
  -- SQL statement to update the "Name" field in the salesforce_account table
  UPDATE "DCA_TEST1_DB"."DB_TEST1"."SALESFORCE_ACCOUNT"
  SET "Name" = 'Name_' || CAST(RANDOM() * 10 AS STRING);
  
  RETURN 'Success';
END;
$$;
```

---

2 - In Script Activity, Call the procedure including double quote like this:

CALL "DCA_TEST1_DB"."DB_TEST1"."UPDATESALESFORCEACCOUNT"();

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMcQG.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Calling a stored procedure stored in Snowflake from Script Activity in ADF

Got similar issue when I tried your Command as below:

[image]

**To resolve this and run stored procedure Successfully You need to use clow statemets:**

```sql
CALL DatabaseName.SchemaName.ProcedureName()
OR
CALL ProcedureName()
```

**Script activity Ran successfully:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When calling a stored procedure, we do not write:

```
CALL PROCEDURE DCA_TEST1_DB.DB_TEST1.UpdateSalesforceAccount();
```

Instead, we write (without **PROCEDURE**):

```
CALL DCA_TEST1_DB.DB_TEST1.UpdateSalesforceAccount();
```